# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$class' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have a class name in variable. I am creating instance and it giving me error. Below is the code example.

```
use app\controller;

$controller = new controller\$class();
```

please help.

Comment: `new controller\{$class}();`

Comment: Hi Rig, Its giving me this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in

Comment: still I didn't get the answer of small question. Hats off stackoverflow....

Comment: No even better than that You have been shown how to solve the problem for yourself Read the DUP post

Answer (score 1):

expecting u got a classname like 'Order' soemthing like the following should work:

```
$class = 'Order';
$order = new $class();
```

U are using the namespace app/controller, so there is no need to write the namespace "controller/" in front of your variable...

that should work:

```
$controller = new $class(); //without "controller/"
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Order' not found in

Comment: Of Course, this will not work as long as there isnt a class, named like that :D
Try it with the class you want to do it!